# No access points available on ubuntu

Tags: wireless, broadcom

I installed ubuntu on macbook air, wifi drivers too. but it is not working,this is wireless info file - http://paste.ubuntu.com/24791533/
I'm newbie with ubuntu, pls help me!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Comment: Elementary is off-topic here.

Comment: Unfortunately your distribution is no (official) flavour of Ubuntu and off topic here. You can ask questions about any Linux distribution over on [Unix.SE]. There's also a StackExchange site specifically for [ElementaryOS.SE] (beta).

Answer (score 1):

If you're not having any luck with Ubuntu Network Manager then you might want to try a manual configuration.

The one thing that missing from your wireless info is your `wpa_supplicant.conf` file, which should contain the following lines:

```
network={
  ssid="your-wifi-network"
  psk="xxxxxx"
}
```

You also need to add a line in `/etc/network/interfaces` to point to your `wpa_supplicant.conf` file:

```
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Once done reboot or restart networking service and this should be enough to associated with an AP. Let me know if you're still struggling...